# How can I pass self reference to object in dart

Tags: dart

I have a class Field and has a copy() method, I want to pass self reference to new object but Dart editor seem not allow. How can I pass self reference to new object like java?

```
class Field 
   Field copy() {
       return new Field(this); 
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem to do such things :

```dart
class Field {
  String name;
  Field(Field other) {
    // init current with other
  }
  Field copy() => new Field(this); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing an opening curly brace and you don't have a constructor. Other than that, there's no reason why this shouldn't work:

```dart
class Field {    
  Field ref;

  Field(this.ref);

  Field copy() {
    return new Field(this);
  }
}

Field a = new Field(null);
Field b = a.copy();
print(identical(a, b.ref)); // true
```